# Java / MySQL on remote server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Ok, sorry if this question is stupid. I followed this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E30_-pQGQXs. Now that I have it compiling in Eclipse, when I upload it to a remote server, how do I get it to work with the jdbc library?

If I try to execute Main.class on a remote server, I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

How do I include the jar or get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure to include the mysql JDBC driver in the classpath on the remote server.

Some app servers have a specific folder to place 3rd party files that get included in the classpath.

Are you using an app server or is this a custom application?

Comment: This is a custom application on my brothers server. It's just a ubuntu server. I'm trying to learn how to do mysql / java server so I can interact with my android apps. I've included the jar in the same location as the class, but its still giving me the error. Can I extract the jdbc class somehow?

Comment: You will have to add the mysql driver jar file to the classpath of the command line that launches the application. Check out the [PATH and CLASSPATH](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) link for more help.

Comment: Ok, i've looked through that link multiple times and I don't quite understand how to update the CLASSPATH still... 

When I enter java -version I get 


java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.1) (6b22-1.10.1-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode, sharing)

This is a ubuntu server and I am accessing it via SSH.

Comment: You basically have to add the jar to the command when launching your application like so: `java -cp .:msql-jdbc-driver.jar your.custom.class.file`. The first "." means to include the current directory, and the second "msql-jdbc-driver.jar" will be the name of the MySQL jdbc dirver that is in the root of the folder. Maybe this link will help too [java - the Java application launcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html).